# Accidentally downgraded libstdc++6:amd64 from 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 to 10-20200411-0ubuntu1

Tags: apt, 22.04, glibc

Why trying to get debug symbols for gcc/g++, I accidentally downgraded libstdc++6:i386 and libstdc++6:amd64 from 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 to 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 by running the following commands

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Followed by errors like

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading libstdc++6:i386 from 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 to 10-20200411-0ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 662778 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libstdc++6:amd64 (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04), to allow configuration of libstdc++6:i386 (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:i386 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1) over (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:i386 (--install):
 package libstdc++6:i386 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 cannot be configured because libstdc++6:amd64 is at a different version (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04)
dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--install):
 package libstdc++6:amd64 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 cannot be configured because libstdc++6:i386 is at a different version (10-20200411-0ubuntu1)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++6:i386
 libstdc++6:amd64
```

Now lots of commands no longer work, especially `apt` for example

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt-get: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
```

Advise needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity's sake here is what I did to solve the problem in my case

Get the packages for the libraries that I accidentally downgraded and then installed them.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libstdc++6_12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libstdc++6_12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04_i386.deb
```

The `--force-all` option mat be required in some cases.